# Easiest way monitor txpool

Tags: go-ethereum, infura, txpool, monitoring

I'm quite new with ethereum development and I'm wondering how to monitor new transactions on the txpool in realtime with the least delay possible. Do I have to run a full geth node or are there other alternatives? I would like something that uses low resources and is fast.

I've tried with Infura websocket but seems limited and doesn't display info until the tx is already in a block.

Any info is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a service like Blocknative: https://www.blocknative.com/. They have a notification service for new transactions.
2. Run one or multiple nodes yourself. The faster you would want new transactions, the more nodes you might want to deploy in different geographical locations.